# Words describing types of justification given

Tags: single-word-requests

There are words to modify justifications or reasons given.

One means "the real motive", and the other means "a plausible explanation, but not the true motivator".

I searched quite a bit, but was unable to find anything. I think one of the words is like "obstinate", but not that, and now that it's in my head, it's all I can bring to mind...

Does anyone know the words I am trying to think of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably thinking of ***ostensible.***

> Stated or appearing to be true, but not necessarily so:
>   *the real dispute which lay behind the ostensible complaint*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ostensible)

It comes from the same root as *ostentatious* — "stretched out to view"; that is in this case, laid out to be viewed as plausible.

Comment: An ostensible motive can conveniently be termed a "pretext".

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw in **ulterior** as a candidate for "the real motive".